# Are method names implicitly cast to delegate types?

Tags: c#, delegates

Im having a little trouble understanding delegates.

I have a delegate that i will invoke when a y character is entered:

```
public delegate void respondToY(string msgToSend);

        private respondToY yHandler;
```

i have a subscribe method in order that calling code can ask to be notified when the delegate is invoked:

```
public void Subscribe(respondToY methodName)
        {
            yHandler += methodName;
        }
```

As far as i can see, to register with this delegate, i need to provide something of the type respondToY. Yet when calling the subscribe method, i can supply either a new instance of the delegate or simply the name of the method. Does this mean that any method matching the delegate signature can be used and will automatically be converted to the correct delegate type?

** Edit **

So on this assumption it would also be valid to supply only a method name to things like click event handlers for buttons (provided the method took the sender, and the relevant event object), it would be converted to the required delegate?

Comment: yep, it's "auto-magic", just has to have return type void and matching parameter types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a *method group conversion*. It converts a method group (basically the name of a method or overloaded methods) to an instance of a delegate type with a compatible signature.

Yes, any compatible method can be used. Note that you can provide a target too - for example:

```
string text = "Hello there";
Func<int, int, string> func = text.Substring;

Console.WriteLine(func(2, 3)); // Prints "llo", which is text.Substring(2, 3)
```

There *must* be a specific delegate type involve though. You can't just use:

```
Delegate x = methodName;
```

... the compiler doesn't know the kind of delegate to create.

For more information, see section 6.6 of the C# 4 language specification.

Note that a method group conversion *always* creates a new instance of the delegate in question - it isn't cached (and can't be without violating the specification.)

Comment: A method group conversion on an instance method will produce a new delegate instance, but I don't think that's true of method group conversions on static methods.  I'm not sure how such things are cached, but it's possible to perform such conversions millions of times without any GC pressure.

Comment: @supercat: If it does that, it's violating the spec, section 6.6: " The result of the conversion is a value of type D, namely a newly created delegate that refers to the selected method and target object." The compiler *does* cache lambda expressions in some cases, but I don't think I've seen it do it for method group conversions. If you have a counter example, I'd love to see it - possibly by email?

Comment: `protected static void delegTest()
        {
            Action a1 = delegTest, a2 = delegTest;
            Console.WriteLine("Delegates equal: {0}", a1 == a2);
        }`

Comment: @supercat: That's using equality, not reference identity. Use `object.ReferenceEquals` and it shows false instead. (And look at the IL.)

Comment: On further testing, I think I was mistaken since there's an `==` overload for delegates.  I'll have to see if I still have the test code where I compared the GC pressure of using a static delegate versus an instance one.  It was in vb.net rather than C#, and it's possible that the behavior of the two languages is different in that regard; if so, that would be a helpful thing to know.

Comment: Hmm... vb.net seems to always create the new delegate too; I wonder what the most idiomatic way is to force the delegate to be created once statically.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know ... yes, the delegate type just makes sure that the signatures match