# Control property depending on other controls' properties? (Listener?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listener

I got used to implement event handlers to set a specific control's property, by creating a checking method and calling it in every handler, like that:

```
private void checkProperties()
{
    myButton.IsEnabled = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTextBox.Text) && myComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1;
}

private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    checkProperties();
}

private void myComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    checkProperties();
}
```

and

```
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="myTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="myTextBox_TextChanged" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,38,0,0" Name="myComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="myComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,84,0,0" Name="myButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="False" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But that gets pretty heavy and redundant when you have a property that depends on 10 or more other controls' properties (just think about a Wizard window and its "Next" button, which should only be enabled if every controls are valid).

**Is there a way to modify a property to automatically change depending on other controls' properties?**

I've read about [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) a bit, but I'm not sure I can, let's say, modify the "IsEnabled" property of myButton to meet my expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to handle events. You should be using element binding, which automatically bind to target properties values. However, both properties in question should be a Dependancy property. It should work in your case.

See this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I like the idea, but it seems to get very complicated when you have a not-so-simple logic: what if I add a CheckBox (that disables or enabled myTextBox for example), and that the condition for myButton to be enabled becomes `myComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1 && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTextBox.Text) || !myTextBox.IsEnabled)` ? I have hard time seeing how to implement that with multibinding, since you only have a values array with no identifiers in your converter.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Multibinding is probably what you need in similar situations - [Multibinding WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176707/multibinding-wpf).

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <Grid.Resources>
        <somenamespace:ValidatorConverter x:Key="ValidatorConverterResource">
    </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox Name="myTextBox"  ... />
        <ComboBox Name="myComboBox" ... />
        <Button Name="myButton" ...>
             <Button.IsEnabled>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValidatorConverterResource}"
                          ConverterParameter="Left">
                <Binding Path="Text"
                         ElementName="myTextBox" />
                <Binding Path="SelectedIndex"
                         ElementName="{myComboBoxSelf}" />
            </MultiBinding>
             </Button.IsEnabled>
        </Button>
</Grid>
```

But it won't actually ease the problem (it will just move it from code-behind [to converters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv)):

```
public class ValidatorConverter: IConverter
{
     public object Converter( ...) //...
     public object ConverterBack( ...) //...
}
```

**About the validation goal**

There is possibly some easy way to do it, but I don't know it, so the easiest way to at least consolidate the issue to where it belongs is to use [bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

In the [model(viewmodel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) make some `IsValid` property(and bind it to the Next IsEnabled directly or even better - [through the command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)) , that will be updated according to the current values of bound properties.

```
public class WizardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     // OnPropertyChanged(String) and PropertyChanged event

     public String Text
     {
         get //..
         set
         {
              this._Text = value;
              Validate();
              this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem")
         }
     }


     public Object SelectedItem
     {
         get //..
         set
         {
              this._SelectedItem = value;
              Validate();
              this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem")
         }
     }

     public bool IsValid { // ...}

     private void Validate()
     {
         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this._Text))
             this.IsValid = false;
         // ....
      }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<somenamespace:WizardViewModel x:Key="WizardViewModelInstance">
// ....
<Grid.DataContext="{StaticResource WizardViewModelInstance}">
// ....
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding Text}"/>
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
<Button  ... IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

Such solution will decouple your logic from view and put everything related to such validation into one place.

**Also:**

If you want to learn about WPF validation you may want to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to learn about WPF commands, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Comment: You kind of shorten your code/explanation too much. I don't understand where I am supposed to bind a with b, and how, neither do I understand this `this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem")` on both properties.

Comment: @Kilazur This is just a skeleton that shows the idea - full working example is a bit to hefty to write. If you haven't worked with MVVM and bindings, then it is good a idea to begin now - I have given few links - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx, and there are a lot of examples and tutorials on web. P.S.: OnPropertyChanged(or RaisePropertyChanged) is just a method that raises the PropertyChanged event defined by INotifyPropertyChanged interface and used by binding engine.

Comment: @Kilazur Delving into MVVM isn't an easy task and even for basic understanding you will have to spend some time, but it is very gratifying knowledge, because WPF is **designed** to be used with MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MVVM instead of code behind. Enabling a button is command logic that is testable, and could be handled very simply in the view model via an [ICommand.CanExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate. No binding would be required since WPF automatically calls CanExecute() when the UI changes.

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand SomeCommand { get; private set; }

    public string Text          { get; set; } //INPC omited for brevity
    public int    SelectedIndex { get; set; } //INPC omited for brevity

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SomeCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSomeCommand, CanDoSomeCommand);
    }

    private void DoSomeCommand()
    {
        //Blah
    }

    private bool CanDoSomeCommand()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text) && this.SelectedIndex > -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get RelayCommand? I got it [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) and it doesn't seem to appreciate method names as parameters.

Comment: @Kilazur You may read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767427/are-method-names-implicitly-cast-to-delegate-types and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760744/c-sharp-automatic-delegate-type-from-method. It will clarify the issue and point to the solution.

Comment: That put apart, what am I supposed to put in DoSomeCommand() in order to enable or disable myButton (or any control using MyViewModel for that matter)?

Comment: You do not have to put in anything to disable your button. WPF will automatically disable buttons that are bound to a command that cannot be run (which it knows by calling CanDoSomeCommand()). DoSomeCommand() is for your code to be run when the button is clicked.